# Award Publicist badge multiple times?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, badges

It is my understanding that Announcer, Booster & Publicist are only awarded once.

I suggest that "Publicist" be awarded multiple times to incentivise users to publicise questions even after they have gained these badges.

**Update:** After a [suggestion form YOU](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90136/award-publicist-badge-multiple-times/90141#90141) I also propose the Publicist badge be altered to require 2000 unique IPs.

Answer (score 7):

Imm, I think this would lead to badges inflation.

Some popular users tweet the questions everyday and can earn gold badges everyday?

Comment: Considering the requirement of the badge, I think it would be fairly hard to get one every week even if you tried to. It's also doing SO lot's of good to have free publicity. Also you shouldn't think of addition or modification of badge only in term of how badge are going to be hand out, but more in term of do people who will get it deserve it.

Comment: @Myself, you mean 5 days requirement? You can only need to wait first 5 days and, then you can get gold badges everyday from that isn't it?

Comment: no, I mean that in general getting the publicist badge every week would be insanely hard to do. So if you say you could earn that badge everyday, I am very skeptical that it would even be possible.

Answer (score 0):

Upon writing the related Answer below, I needed to copy the badge descriptions for Publicist, Booster, and Announcer.

https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/354077/281934 <sup>see what I did there?</sup>

> **Publicist**: Share a link to a post later visited by 1000 unique IP addresses. **This badge can be awarded multiple times.**

It appears that the Share Link badges were [quietly updated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/90136/3) in 2012 to allow multiple awards.

I found this question while wondering if the badges can be awarded multiple times *for the same share link*, of which I do not yet have the answer.

Comment: I see what you did there, but links to posts on the same site don't count :)

Comment: If you have a new question, you should ask a new question. ;) But the answer is "no".