# Can you see how many times a link in your question or comment was clicked?

Tags: support, hyperlinks

If you posted a link in a question or in a comment, can you see how many times the link was clicked?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, there isn't a way to do this.  **Please don't use URL shorteners to get around this limitation**.

It is possible to work around this using a URL shortener, but you really, really shouldn't.  URL shorteners are [heavily discouraged](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/113660/165261), and persistent use of them in this manner is likely to attract moderator attention.  It also creates more work for others to remove them from your posts via edits, which is both encouraged and something to which [substantial effort has been dedicated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/99136/165261) in the past.

If the site you're linking to is your own website, you could put a campaign tracking parameter in the link, and track clicks via your preferred analytics software.  Don't forget to [disclose your affiliation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/promotion), too.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the "share" functionality under a Stack Exchange post, you will get a unique link that includes your user id, like so: [Can you see how many times a link in your question or comment was clicked?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/354066/281934)

> Share a link to this question (includes your user id)

This link will award Stack Exchange badges for 25, 300, and 1000 unique IP address visits.

> **Publicist** (Gold): Share a link to a post later visited by 1000 unique IP addresses.
> **Booster** (Silver): Share a link to a post later visited by 300 unique IP addresses.
> **Announcer** (Bronze): Share a link to a post later visited by 25 unique IP addresses.

So if you're sharing a Stack Exchange link, using the "share" link is a sanctioned way to see a rough estimate of how many people have clicked your link. Just watch your inbox for badges.

Comment: Thanks, interesting information, thought not exactly what I meant: how often link in a question was clicked, not external link out of the stack exchange.